# operator= become to copy construtor in c++11 test

Tags: c++11, constructor, move-semantics, assignment-operator

I have the following test in g++ 4.8.1 :

g++ -std=c++11 testclass.cpp -o testclass.exe

```
template<typename T>
class XRef
{
    private :
        int inum ;
        T * ptr ;
        bool owner ;
    public :
        XRef(int i,T *ptrx):inum{i},ptr{ptrx},owner{true}
        {cout << "natural" << endl ;}

        XRef(XRef& x):inum{x.inum},ptr{x.ptr},owner{false}
        {cout << "copy" << endl ;}

        XRef& operator=(XRef& x)
        {
            inum = x.inum ;
            ptr = x.ptr ;
            owner = false ;
            cout << "assign" << endl ;
            return *this ;
        }

        XRef(XRef&& x):inum{x.inum},ptr{move(x.ptr)},owner{true}
        {cout << "move" << endl ;}

        ~XRef()
        {
            if(owner)
                delete ptr ;
        }
} ;

int main()
{
    char *ptr1 ;
    char *ptr2 ;
    ptr1 = (char *) malloc(100) ;
    ptr2 = (char *) malloc(100) ;

    XRef<char> x1 = XRef<char>(1,ptr1) ;
    cout <<"==============" << endl ;
    XRef<char> x2 = x1 ;
    cout <<"==============" << endl ;
    XRef<char> x3(x2) ;
    cout <<"==============" << endl ;
    XRef<char> x4(XRef<char>(123,ptr2)) ;
    cout <<"==============" << endl ;
    XRef<char> x5(move(XRef<char>(123,ptr2))) ;
    cout <<"==============" << endl ;
    XRef<char> x6{123,ptr2} ;
}
```

Then , the output :

```
natural
==============
copy
==============
copy
==============
natural
==============
natural
move
==============
natural
```

What surprise me is that :  XRef x2 = x1 ;
 , I think this should call XRef& operator=(XRef& x)  ,  but this test showes it call 
XRef(XRef& x)  instead ....

I like to know what i do is wrong , so that operator=  is not called !!

Edit :

```
XRef<char> x7{123,ptr2} ;
cout <<"==============" << endl ;
x7 = x6 ;
cout <<"==============" << endl ;
```

Showes :

```
natural
==============
assign
==============
```

So ,

```
XRef<char> x2 = x1 ;
```

is different with

```
XRef<char> x7{123,ptr2} ;
x7 = x6 ;
```

How come this happened ?

PS. I refered to : [copy construtor called extra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865239/copy-construtor-called-extra?rq=1)  for reference ...

Comment: The line `XRef<char> x2 = x1 ;` is __creating a new object__ so the copy constructor is called (even though it looks something like an assignment). [See this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5368273/445976)

Comment: Thank you,Blastfurnace,that is a excellent information to me ~!!

Comment: Your code has Undefined Behavior since it invokes double freeing memory.

Comment: Thanks you,soon,this is still a test case , some works under debug, it is very kind of you for the kind information !!

Comment: You should either do the memory allocation-deallocation with `new[]` and `delete[]` OR with `malloc` and `free`. What you currently have may accidentally work but it is undefined behavior and tools like valgrind would catch these type of bugs.

Comment: Thanks, Ali , I got your point , appreciate your suggestion !!